# Why should i use cronet over volley/retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, android-volley

I came across a a section on cronet here

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/cronet

it states that

> Cronet is the Chromium network stack made available to Android apps as a library.

Has any one used this library before? What are its use cases?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Volly documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) it is **not** suitable for large downloads or streaming operations:

> Volley is **not** suitable for large download or streaming operations, since Volley holds all responses in memory during parsing. For large download operations, consider using an alternative like DownloadManager.

And according to [Cronet documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/cronet) it provides higher throughput and lower latency:

> Cronet takes advantage of multiple technologies that **reduce the latency** and **increase the throughput** of the network requests that your app needs to work.

> The Cronet Library handles the requests of apps used by millions of people on a daily basis, such as **YouTube**, Google App, Google Photos, and Maps - Navigation & Transit.

Answer (score -1):

You can read these two article to know more about cronet .
[Article 1](https://medium.com/@cchiappini/discover-cronet-4c7b4812407)       [Article 2](https://medium.com/@kelvinwatson/cronet-integration-with-livedata-and-kotlin-coroutines-bf6a3db85544) .